# Classification error Levels in factors of new data do not match original data

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have this data set:

```
"chr","start","stop","strand","num_probes","segment_mean","is_nocnv"
chr18,52502759,52502887,*,2,-2.387,YES
chr18,52508963,68598272,*,9546,-0.3843,YES
chrX,17018571,63154896,*,18479,-0.0448,YES
chrX,63161754,63812965,*,265,-0.5375,YES
chrX,63816350,66632343,*,1071,0.1047,YES
chrX,66632547,67941468,*,558,-0.5452,YES
chrX,67947143,94288567,*,10251,-0.0625,YES
chr1,5902314,10246654,*,2415,-0.1312,NO
chr1,10249962,10255256,*,4,-1.4639,NO
chrX,66632547,67941468,*,605,-0.5472,NO
chrX,67947143,90967744,*,11378,-0.0608,NO
chrX,90968512,90971771,*,9,-0.9191,NO
chrX,90971889,92325108,*,520,-0.088,NO
etc...
```

And i write this code:

```
mydata= read.csv("prova.csv")
str(mydata)
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2,nrow(mydata),replace=TRUE, prob= c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- mydata[ind==1,]
testData <- mydata[ind==2,]

myFormula <- is_nocnv ~ chr + start + stop + strand + num_probes +     segment_mean
albero <- ctree(myFormula, data=trainData)
#check the prediction
table(predict(albero),trainData$is_nocnv)
```

Then I have new test dataset with one row:

```
"chr","start","stop","strand","num_probes","segment_mean","is_nocnv"
chr18,52502759,52502887,*,2,-2.387,a
```

of this test dataset i want predict the value of "is_nocnv" ("a" is not a really value)

For my goal I insert this code:

```
testData= read.csv("TEST_DATA.csv")
testPred <- predict(albero,newdata= testData)
table(testPred,testData$is_nocnv)
```

HERE:
I have the error:

```
> testPred <- predict(albero,newdata= testData)
 Error in checkData(oldData, RET) : 
  Levels in factors of new data do not match original data
```

I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *new* `testData` doesn't have the same levels of your `trainData` on the `factor` variables (in your example `chr` and `is_nocnv`).

Check with `levels(testData$is_nocnv)` and `levels(trainData$is_nocnv)`.
(the same for `$chr`).

`levels` need to be equal.

From this string:

```
chr18,52502759,52502887,*,2,-2.387,a
```

it seems that `is_nocnv = a`, but in your train you have only `YES/NO` labels.

Be sure to have the **same labels** and the same `levels`.

```
testData$is_nocnv <- factor("YES", levels = c("NO","YES")) # or "NO"
```

or better:

```
testData$is_nocnv <- factor("YES", levels = levels(trainData$is_nocnv))
```

The same for the other variable `chr`:

```
testData$chr <- factor("chr18", levels = levels(trainData$chr))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i insert levels(testData) and levels(trainData) I obtain NULL. Instead, this string: testData$is_nocnv <- factor("YES", levels = c("NO","YES")) work right, thanks

Comment: I obtain this : > levels(trainData$is_nocnv)
[1] "NO"  "YES"    and  > levels(testData$is_nocnv) 
[1] "NO"  "YES"

Comment: This is the problem: > levels(trainData$chr)
 [1] "chr1"  "chr10" "chr11" "chr12" "chr13" "chr14" "chr15" "chr16" "chr17" "chr18" "chr19" "chr2"  "chr20" "chr21" "chr22" "chr3"  "chr4"  "chr5" 
[19] "chr6"  "chr7"  "chr8"  "chr9"  "chrX"  "chrY"     |||||    > levels(testData$chr) 
[1] "chr18"       But i want classify new entry

Comment: indicates the chromosome

Comment: in original file i have more chr, in test file i have 1 chr that i want classify  with the rules learned with classification. but the problem seems to be that in the test file I have only one chr